# Jersey client - unmarshall a ClientResponse entity body of type XML to a POJO

Tags: xml-serialization, jersey

I've read through a lot of the examples here and I still can't isolate my coding mistake. I'm trying to use the built-in Jersey-client MessageBodyReaders.

My pojo looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"name", "complexId", "libraryList", "partitionList", "nextLinks"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "LibraryComplex")

public class YapiLibraryComplex 
{
    @XmlTransient LibraryComplex libComplex;
    String name;
    int complexId;
    List<Integer> libraryList;
    List<String> partitionList;
    List<URI> nextLinks;
         .
         .
         .
```

my service looks like this:

```
@Path ("/")
public class YAPIWebService
{
    @Context Application yapiAppl;
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;


    @GET
    @Produces ("application/xml")
    //@Produces ("MediaType.APPLICATION_XML")
    public Response getLibraryComplex()
    {
        LibraryComplex libComplex = (((YAPIapplication) yapiAppl).getLibComplex());
        YapiLibraryComplex yapiLibPlex;
            .
            .
            .

        return Response.ok(yapiLibPlex).build();
```

and my client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   //client client = new client();
    System.out.println("the beginning");
    //ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    //cc.getClasses().add(com.sun.jersey.api.core.);
    //Client c = Client.create(cc);
    Client c = Client.create();
    WebResource rsrc = c.resource("http://localhost:7101/");
    //ClientResponse response = rsrc.get(ClientResponse.class);

    ClientResponse response = rsrc.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);

    YapiLibraryComplex libPlex = response.getEntity(YapiLibraryComplex.class);
    System.out.println("the libPlex object is " + libPlex.toString());

    String entityBody = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("the response as a string is " + entityBody);
    System.out.println("the status is " + response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("the links are " + response.getLinks());

    System.out.println("the end");
}
```

}

And my stack trace:

the beginning

Jul 25, 2012 6:47:22 PM com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.SAXParserContextProvider getInstance WARNING: JAXP feature XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING cannot be set on a SAXParserFactory. External general entity processing is disabled but other potential security related features will not be enabled. org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing   at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.setFeature(JXSAXParserFactory.java:129)

```
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.SAXParserContextProvider.getInstance(SAXParserContextProvider.java:80)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.SAXParserContextProvider.getInstance(SAXParserContextProvider.java:54)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.ThreadLocalSingletonContextProvider$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalSingletonContextProvider.java:64)

at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:141)

at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:131)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.ThreadLocalSingletonContextProvider$2.getValue(ThreadLocalSingletonContextProvider.java:77)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.readFrom(XMLRootElementProvider.java:113)

at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)

at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:554)

at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)

at .tape.acs.yapi.smokeTest.main(smokeTest.java:32) Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Error creating SAXSource - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: SAX feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' not supported.]

at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:115)

at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:554)

at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)

at .tape.acs.yapi.smokeTest.main(smokeTest.java:32) Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Error creating SAXSource - with linked exception:[org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: SAX feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' not supported.]

at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getSAXSource(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:205)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.readFrom(XMLRootElementProvider.java:113)

at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)

... 3 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: SAX feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' not supported.

at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.setFeature(NonValidatingParser.java:1975)

at oracle.xml.parser.v2.SAXParser.setFeature(SAXParser.java:270)

at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.newSAXParser(JXSAXParserFactory.java:92)

at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getSAXSource(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:201)

... 5 more Process exited with exit code 1.
```